# LDAP: Search for substring and match special chars against plain ascii

Tags: ldap, openldap, ldap-query

My scenario is that I have a search feature that you can filter users entries with. The user passes a search string, it matching entries will be presented.

The filter created is

`(displayname=*$SEARCH*)`

with $SEARCH being the input from the user.

This works so far. But now, the user is typing in `sud` (which is expended to `*sud*`) and expects to find the entry with the displayname "asüdf". This works on Active Directory, but not on OpenLDAP (did not try other servers).

LDAP has a proximity operator, ~=. It does not accept wildcards however, i.e. a sub string search is not possible.

Is there a generic way and how to accomplish it on LDAP on client side? Or does the LDAP server need extra configuration (also, generic or vendor-specific?)

Comment: Don't provide facilities like this. The leading wildcard implies a sequential search.

Comment: @EJP What do you suggest to do instead, when search is a requirement?

Answer (score 0):

If you are planning on doing approximate or sounds like (=~) matching you need to create a ***sounds like*** index on the directory server for the attributes you are searching against.

This is analogous to adding a ***substring*** index if you are going to perform substring searches against an attribute.

As well, it may not match your purpose perfectly as it is phonetic which will vary by language.

Comment: Whether the index is there or not, the proximity operator (i.e. the sounds like search) does not work with wildcards. That's my problem.